Proposition 12, Section 5.6 of Hungerford’s Algebra

Let $F$ be a finite dimensional extension field of $K$ and $N$ a normal extension field of $K$ containing $F$. The number of distinct $K$-monomorphisms $F\to N$ is precisely $[F : K]_s$, the separable degree of $F$ over $K$.
Sketch of proof: Let $S$ be the maximal subfield of $F$ separable over $K$. Every $K$-monomorphism $S\to N$ extends to a $K$-automorphism of $N$ (since $N$ is normal over $K$) and hence (by restriction) to a $K$-monomorphism $F\to N$. We claim that the number of distinct $K$-monomorphisms $F\to N$ is the same as the number of distinct $K$-monomorphisms $S\to N$. $\cdots \cdots$, which proves our claim. Consequently, it suffices to assume that $F$ is separable over $K$ (that is, $F = S$) $\cdots \cdots$

$(1)$ I don’t understand why we assume $F$ is separable over $K$ based on the fact that $| \{ K\text{-monomorphisms } F\to N \} |=| \{ K\text{-monomorphisms } S\to N \} |$.
$(2)$ How to show normal extension $N$ of $K$ containing $F$ always exists?

I got answer of $(2)$ using normal closure, which is theorem 16 section 5.3 in Hungerford’s Algebra.

Assume the statement is verified when $K\subseteq F$ is a separable extension. Then for an arbitrary extension $K\subseteq F$ and $S={x\in F:\text{$x$ is separable over $K$} }$, we have
\begin{multline*}
[F:K]_s\overset{(1)}{=}\dim_K S\overset{(2)}{=} [S:K]_s   \overset{(3)}{=}| { K\text{-monomorphisms } S\to N } |\
\overset{(4)}{=}| { K\text{-monomorphisms } F\to N } |,
\end{multline*} (to be continued)

(to continue) where $(1),&, (2)$ is definition of separability degree (for $(2)$ note that $S={x\in S: \text{$x$ is separable over $K$ }}$); $(3)$ is because the assertion is verified when the extension is separable and we apply it to $K\subseteq S$. $(4)$ is also verified (which your post put it into ellipsis).

@Asigan Thank you so much for the answer. Can I write your comment as answer (community wiki)?

Sure, you can write it as an answer and put it to the community wiki.

I have written comments (answer my question) of user Asigan, since comments are temporary.
$(1)$ Assume the statement is verified when $K\subseteq F$ is a separable extension. Then for an arbitrary extension $K\subseteq F$ and $S=\{x\in F\mid x\text{ is separable over }K\}$, we have
$$[F:K]_s \stackrel{(1)}{=} [S:K] \stackrel{(2)}{=} [S:K]_s\stackrel{(3)}{=} |\{K\text{-monomorphism }S\to N\}| \stackrel{(4)}{=} |\{K\text{-monomorphism }F\to N\}|$$
where $(1)$ and $(2)$ is definition of separability degree (for $(2)$ note that $S=\{x\in S\mid x \text{ is separable over }K\}$); $(3)$ is because the assertion is verified when the extension is separable and we apply it to $K\subseteq S$. $(4)$ is also verified.
$(2)$ Use normal closure.
